# Sed doesn't replace my text properly

Tags: regex, sed

My following regex in Sed doesn't extract the file I want without the `#30` substring. 
Could you please help pointing out what I am missing here?

```
[machine]# echo "//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb#70"  | sed  's/\(.*rb\)#\d+$/\1/g'
```

Output:     `//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb#70`

What I want is simply: `//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb`   without `#70` substring.

Thanks in advance

PL

Comment: I don't recall if `#` is a special character to `sed`, but it would be worthwhile to forcibly escape it:  `... sed 's/\(.*rb\)[#]\d+$/\1/g'` or perhaps `... sed 's/\(.*rb\)\#\d+$/\1/g'`  It may even be considered a comment character by the shell, and thus need to be escaped for that reason.

Comment: @abiessu I don't think it means anything for `sed`, and inside single quotes it shouldn't be interpreted by the shell either.

Comment: @LevLevitsky correct, `#` is just another plain old character to sed, it;s the `\d` and the `+` that are the problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The flavor of regular expression understood by `sed` by default doesn't include either `\d` for digits or `+` for "1 or more".

This will work:

```
sed 's/\(.*\.rb\)#[0-9][0-9]*$/\1/g'
```

Or you could turn on "extended" regular expression syntax with `-E`, which makes the `+` work (though still not `\d`), and swaps the meaning of backslashed vs non-backslashed parentheses:

```
sed -E 's/(.*\.rb)#[0-9]+$/\1/g'
```

Both of the above commands will work even on non-GNU sed, as you get by default on BSD and Mac OS X systems.  In normal mode (without the `-E`), GNU sed also understands `\+` to mean the same as bare `+` in extended mode, but BSD sed does not.

If all you're trying to do is get rid of the `#digits`, though, you can do it more simply.  Sed regexes aren't anchored to the start of the line, so you don't have to include the filename - just replace the part you don't want with nothing at all:

```
sed 's/#[0-9][0-9]*$//'
```

or

```
sed -E 's/#[0-9]+$//'
```

If your real problem does require the fancy version, though, you could also use Perl, which has the advantage that there's relatively few (almost no) changes in regex syntax across versions. It also understands that `\d` syntax you tried to use:

```
perl -pe 's/(.*\.rb)#\d+$/\1/g'
```

Comment: Thanks for all the replies. sed 's/#[0-9][0-9]*$//' worked perfectly.

Comment: Ooops, I thought I already clicked the check-mark, but apparently it wasn't so....Already clicked the check-mark as the answer. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

With GNU sed, your command works if you use `-E` and change `\d` to `[0-9]` or `[[:digit:]]`:

```
echo "//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb#70" | sed -E 's/(.*rb)#[0-9]+$/\1/g'
//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb
```

Depending on the context, you may be able to use a simpler command, such as

```
sed 's/#[0-9]\+//g'
```

Answer (score 0):

You got the answer but have you considered simply:

```
$ echo "//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb#70" | cut -d'#' -f1
//dir1/dir2/dir3/component/file.rb
```